# Kendo Autocomplete Authorization Headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I can't figure out why my Kendo Autocomplete widget is not sending the authorization headers in the request to the server:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: 'odata',
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: myApiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', myAuthorizationValue);
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#myAutocompleteField').kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: 'fieldName',
    filter: 'contains',
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: dataSource
});
```

When I check the server response in dev tools, I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` error from the server. Looking at the Request Headers, I don't see the `Authorization` property at all.

What do I need to do to get the Authorization header to be included with the request?

**Update:**

I've continued to explore this problem. If I just do a typical `$.ajax` request with the same object as `transport.read` in the Kendo DataSource parameter, it sends the headers and I get a successful response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myApiUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', myAuthorizationValue);
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log('success!');
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum post on Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/odata-not-working-with-custom-authorization-header), when using `type: 'odata'` the server expects to be working with JSONP and will not send Auth headers.

Commenting out that line, as below, will send the Auth headers, but it sends the searched query using a filters array, instead of typical ODATA parameters (which makes sense):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    //type: 'odata',  // this causes the auth headers to not be sent
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: myApiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', myAuthorizationValue);
            }
        }
    }
});

// Parameters sent
filter[filters][0][value]:sprint
filter[filters][0][operator]:contains
filter[filters][0][field]:fieldName
filter[filters][0][ignoreCase]:true
filter[logic]:and
```

Interestingly, I found elsewhere on the Internet someone using `type: 'odata-v4'`, which does sent the Auth headers and sends the ODATA filter parameters properly.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: 'odata-v4',
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: myApiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', myAuthorizationValue);
            }
        }
    }
});

// Parameters Sent
$format:json
$filter:contains(tolower(fieldName),'sprin') // sprin is the search string
$count:true
```